# vagrant virtualbox disk grows in size for no reason

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using a vagrant with virtualbox for my development environment but the disk size grows in size for no reason. When I first create the box and provision it, the disk size is about 4GB but after 3 months of use, the disk size is about 18GB even I didn't install anything new all that time. I just can't explain what takes all those gigs.

Any idea why this happens or any solution? Having multiple boxes just eats up a lot of my disk space for no reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing you would need to do is to check how much space is really consumed in your VM. VirtualBox (as well as VMWare) uses dynamic size allocation so they will grow your file size when needed but they never free up the space unless you specifically ask for it.

run `df -m` to check how much space is really used by each partition, if you believe a partition has too much space, go on the mount point and clean some files.

save space of unallocated block on the VM

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M  || echo "dd exit code $? is suppressed"
$ rm -f /EMPTY
```

now back on your host, you will need to claim the free space

```
$ VBoxManage modifyhd <name>.vdi --compact
```

This option runs only for `vdi` format, if you have `vmdk` you will need to convert into `vdi` first

```
$ VBoxManage clonehd <name>.vmdk <name>.vdi --format vdi
$ VBoxManage modifyhd <name>.vdi --compact
$ rm <name>.vmdk
$ VBoxManage clonehd <name>.vdi <name>.vmdk --format vmdk
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I can't figure out what exactly is taking so much space. Folder /var seems to be the largest, about 3.3G but all the sub folders summed up is about 1.5G.

$ sudo du -hc --max-depth=1 var/ | sort -hr

3.3G var/
3.3G total
637M var/lib
587M var/cache
33M var/crash
5.5M var/log
1.4M var/backups
28K var/spool
20K var/www
20K var/tmp
4.0K var/snap
4.0K var/opt
4.0K var/mail
4.0K var/local

/var is largest from my machine but i can't figure out exactly is eating so much space? 3.3G total but all sub folder don't take more than 1.5GB/

Comment: so just run the command - if your total used space on hard drive is less than 4gb compacting the vm disk will shrink the size of the file

Comment: VBoxManage: error: Failed to clone medium
VBoxManage: error: Cannot register the hard disk '/Users/artem/VirtualBox VMs/ReactMusic/box-disk1.vmdk' {2206b495-10ee-4781-8edd-66a7f08ec6b6} because a hard disk '/Users/artem/VirtualBox VMs/ReactMusic/box-disk1.vmdk' with UUID {0de305a2-22e7-40af-8226-75d7f31a7637} already exists
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCloneMedium(HandlerArg *)" at line 954 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp

Comment: It looks like after cloning a vmdk into a vdi, the --compact step is unecessary, the new file is already compacted.